# How to execute more than one command in terminal over SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh, raspbian

I'm currently connecting to a Raspberry Pi Model B running Raspbian via SSH.
I'm trying to program a script to run several commands continuously; I want these two commands to run along side each other:

```
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100 
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.1
```

Does putting one command after another in a Shell script allow them both to run together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nohup to run these commands together, i.e:

```
nohup arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100 > /var/log/logfile1 &
nohup arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.1 > /var/log/logfile2 &
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question, what does the "> /var/log/logfile1 &" part mean? Sorry, a little newbie

Comment: All the command line output will be directed to /var/log/logfile1, If you don't set this part it will be saved in a file called nohup.out in the directory where you run the command